# Flash ExternalInterface.addCallback error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

So I have one function:

```
public function handleOnSave(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var ml:MultipartURLLoader = new MultipartURLLoader();
            var bmData:BitmapData = scrollView.getBitmapData();
            ml.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSaveComplete);

            // simple string data
            ml.addVariable("ad_id", ParamsObject.lastInstance.param_id);
            ml.addVariable("ad_type", ParamsObject.lastInstance.param_type);
            ml.addVariable("image_width", bmData.width);
            ml.addVariable("image_height", bmData.height);
            ml.addVariable("save_data", scrollView.getSavedData());

            trace(scrollView.getSavedData());
            var jpgSource:Bitmap = null;

            var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(99);
            var jpgStream:ByteArray = jpgEncoder.encode(scrollView.getBitmapData());
            var pngStream:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bmData);
            ml.addFile(jpgStream, 'test2.jpg', "pic" , 'image/jpeg');
            trace(pngStream.length + ' ' + jpgStream.length );
            ml.load("/flash/uploadFP.php");
        }
```

I have button to trigger it like:

```
save_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleOnSave);
```

What I want to do is to put this button outside flash and to call this function with Java Script using ExternalInterfacе like:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("save",handleOnSave);
```

but the browser returns

`uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. Use a try/catch block to find error.`

I try to call function which only return alert for success and it worked. I searched for this and the only thing which people suggest is to use

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
```

I did it but the problem remains.

Edited:

OK try/catch returned **Error #2176**!

Comment: For reference: #2176 - Certain actions, such as those that display a pop-up window, may only be invoked upon user interaction, for example by a mouse click or button press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing noticed is

```
 public function handleOnSave(e:MouseEvent):void ...
```

has event `e` as parameter, which you won't be able to pass from Javascript.

As `e` is not used inside `handleOnSave` you can define the function like

```
  public function handleOnSave(e:MouseEvent = null):void ...
```

So in Actiobscript, it should be like

```
  public function handleOnSave(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
   .....
   .....
  }

  ExternalInterface.addCallback("save",handleOnSave);
```

and from Javascript you can call something like

```
  document[*flash movie id*].save();
```

Please share your Javascript code to see whether anything else is wrong.

EDIT:

As it shows to find out the error

```
 public function handleOnSave(e:MouseEvent = null):String{
        try{

            ...existing code...

        }catch(error:Error){

            return error.message;

        }

        return "";
 }
```

and receive the error in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks but I changed it to e:MouseEvent = null but this is not the problem I try to make this throw keyboard event and it worked handleOnSave started. Also make another function with simple alert to chek if it works and it did. And the problem is somewhere in handleOnSave function but I can`t figure it out

Comment: Then as it shows use try...catch and find error. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Or you can try a create a debug configuration with this url and identify the issue.

Comment: I make try catch and it return Error #2176

Comment: Oh... Now I got the issue.. you can't execute the function without a user ineraction in Flash UI.  It is the same issue discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859336/how-to-get-around-flash-error-2176